# Can Spring create differently configured beans based on a Qualifier annotation without using constructors?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

What I want is to configure two (or more) Singletons with a slightly different internal dependency.

Let's say I have a Car:

```
@Component
public Car {
    @Inject private Engine engine;
    @Inject private Chassis chassis;
}
```

Now the Engine comes in 2 variants, @Standard and @Powerful

What I want is to inject a Car, and qualify this injection with @Standard or @Powerful, without actually having to create 2 Car instances myself.

In other words when I write:

```
@Inject @Powerful Car car;
```

I want Spring to create (or use existing) singleton Car with the standard Chassis and the Powerful Engine.

But when I write:

```
@Inject @Standard Car car;
```

I want Spring to create (or use existing) singleton Car with the standard Chassis and the Standard Engine.

So far I can only manage this by giving Car a constructor and doing this myself in a @Configuration class.  This is ok for this example, but tiresome if there's like 10 injections for Car.

```
@Bean @Powerful
public Car car1() {
    return new Car(new PowerfulEngine(), new Chassis());
}

@Bean @Standard
public Car car1() {
    return new Car(new StandardEngine(), new Chassis());
}

@Bean @Standard @Sedan
public Car car1() {
    return new Car(new StandardEngine(), new SedanChassis());
}

etc...
```

There must be an easier way...

Can Spring just create these two beans for me?  What about even more if there's 3 engine types?  Or 3 engine types and 5 chassis types (meaning there can be 15 differently configured Car objects)?

ie:

```
@Inject @Powerful @Sedan Car car;
```

Where @Sedan is a Chassis variant...

Comment: No, Spring does not have such built in functionality.

Comment: Confirming @SotiriosDelimanolis statement, didn't come through such Spring feature.

Comment: And how should spring know your @sedan references to SedanChassis? Well, probably you can do that with reflections, i dont understand all the details of your question.

Comment: It would know this, because the respective Engines/Chassis etc are also annotated with the same annotation (@Sedan for a chassis or @Powerful for an engine).